# Align Text and Images perfectly next to Each Other

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-imageview, textview

I am trying to line up the text and images next to each other in a perfect line but cant quite get it center.

As you see with the image it's almost center next to each other but not perfectly what am I missing

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image_ls"


         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"

         />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image_ls"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"

        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use linear layout with horizontal orientation and gravity center and proper weight to each view inside it.

Comment: use android:gravity="center_vertical" in RelaiveLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try This Code:- 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image_ls"


         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"

         />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image_ls"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"

        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/image_ls" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/image_ls" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Use LinearLayout to fix android widgets in vertical or horizontal.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```